# Как сделать 'сон' бота отдельно для каждого пользователя? (Aiogram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, asyncio, aiogram-3.x

Я хочу сделать команду `/sleep {число}`, но дело в том, что если ее выполнит один пользователь, то бот застынет и у всех остальных,как можно сделать команду отдельно для каждого пользователя? (Есть вариант с занесением никнейса пользователя в лист, и убирать через время, но думаю есть более удобный способ)

Comment: Делаешь lock для пользователя и перед отправкой сообщений пользователю чекаешь есть лок или нет

Comment: @mego4iter спасибо, но я написал про этот способ, либо я чего то не понимаю? Имеется ввиду забив в лист и проверка, или это что-то отдельное?

Comment: Что конкретно вы подразумеваете под командой sleep для бота?
Я так понял, что бот не присылает пользователю сообщения в течении определённого времени.
Если так то делаешь таблицу "ключь-значение", где ключь ид пользователя а значение до кокого времени бот находиться в состоянии сна.
Теперь перед отправкой сообщения пользователю проверяешь, есть ли он в этой таблице и до скольки для этого пользователя бот находиться в состоянии сна.

Comment: @mego4iter спасибо, я это и имел ввиду, значит прийдется продолжать через лист